# VS 2008 Open Word Document - Memory Error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, automation, ms-word, ms-office

I am executing the following code that worked fine in a vs2003(1.1) but seems to have decided otherwise now that I'm using vs2008(2.0/3.5):

```
Dim wordApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
Dim wordDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document

missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
wordApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()
Dim wordfile As Object
wordfile = "" ' path and file name goes here

wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(wordfile, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing)
```

The error thrown when the Open is attempted is :
"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Does anyone have any idea how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- Word installation is sane (does opening a simple document via double-click work)?
- no anti-virus tool is running (maybe the tool is strict about COM automation)?

And another remark: Since you are using VB.Net there is no need to write all the "missing" parameters, The following code looks much simpler:

```
Dim wordApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
Dim wordDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
Dim wordfile As String

wordApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
wordfile = "" ' path and file name goes here

wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(wordfile)
```